# How to modify sample Heroku facebook app to show friend's likes

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, heroku

In the sample app that Heroku starts you out with when you make a Facebook php app, there's this line.

```
$likes = idx($facebook->api('/me/likes?limit=4'), 'data', array());
```

This will get 4 of my likes and store them in an array. But what I want to do is get 4 things that my friend likes.

I tried replacing "me" with the id of a friend, but it didn't work. What changes do I have to make to fetch my friend's likes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You obviously need the [`friends_likes`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) permission. Here's an official [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/481/) on how to pull the movies your friends' like.

Comment: obviously the tutorial needs your attention. For example you should replace `perms` with `scope`...etc